# How can I save a high score using PlayerPrefs?

Tags: unity, c#

I'd like to save the player's high score using Unity's [`PlayerPrefs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) API. This is the code I have so far:

```
public int coins;
public int score;
public int highscore;
public int points;
public Text pointsText;
public Text HighScore;
public Text Score;
public Text coinsText;

void start(){
    highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("HighScore");
}
void Update () {
    if(points > highscore){
        highscore = points;
        HighScore.text = ("HighScore: " + points);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("HighScore", highscore);
        PlayerPrefs.Save ();
    }
    score = points;
    pointsText.text = ("x  " + points); 



    Score.text = ("Score  " + points);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Score", points);

    coinsText.text = ("Coins  " + points);

}
```

However, it does not work. Every time I restart the game, the high score is 0 again. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3):

The problem appears to be, as I noted in the comments originally, that you have a function called `start()` in your code (which I am presuming is a `MonoBehavior` class). C# is case-sensitive, however, and the MonoBehavior function that is invoked at the start is called [`Start()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) (with an upper-case "S").

Your `start()` function is likely not being called at all, which means the code to read the high score from the `PlayerPrefs` is never executed, at the high score remains at its default value of 0.

Comment: can you change that script to work? pls?

Comment: @RicardoCarapeto Capitalize "start." Change the "s" to "S" -- that is all I am suggesting.